# How do I draw this weird space

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to solve this question:

[image]

My attempt of solution:

[image]

Note first I use the stereographic projection to see the sphere is homeomorphic to the plane with a point at infinity, after this we get this infinite block with height 1 with a segment of height 1 at infinity.

Am I right? I fell I'm wrong, this space seems very weird.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just draw a 2-sphere in a 2-sphere and define the space in between to be filled.

Comment: basically it is a 2-dimensional annulus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics)

Comment: I'm sorry, but Why?

Comment: the "$\times I$" means that you can paramatrize it. So just parametrize it, eg. by saying that the inner sphere is $0$ and the outer sphere is $1$.

Comment: and by this I mean that $X \times I$ is a collection of $(X,t)$ with $t \in I$.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks

Comment: yes and you are reminding me that I am really hungry.

Comment: But where am I wrong? can I say your space is homeomorphic to mine? (you can answer later) :)